# Simplifying method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this method which works fine but I'm thinking that it may be improved, either for readability and/or efficience.

```
def default_something
    something =
    Legal::Something.find_for_A_in_placea('xx', claim.blabla.identifier) ||
    Legal::Something.find_for_B_in_placeb('xx', claim.eligible.first.bleble.indivcode) ||
    Legal::Something.find_for_B_in_placeb('xx', claim.eligible.last.blublu.indivcode) ||
    Legal::Something.find_by(id: DEFAULT_SOMETHING_ID)

    {
     'name' => something.name,
     'day' => something.meta_data[:day],
     'hour' => something.meta_data[:hour],
    }
end
```

I can "beautify it" by creating some more methods like:

```
def default_something
    something = def A || def B || (etc)
end

def A
  Legal::Something.find_for_A_in_placea('xx', claim.blabla.identifier)
end

def B
  Legal::Something.find_for_B_in_placeb('xx', claim.eligible.first.bleble.indivcode) ||
  Legal::Something.find_for_B_in_placeb('xx', claim.eligible.last.blublu.indivcode)    
end
```

In addition I should say:

- `find_for_B` part only retrieves a value when claim.eligible.first.bleble.indivcode || claim.eligible.last.blublu.indivcode = 'ASL'

Is the "beautified" version the way to go?
And/or should I add an if statement regarding

```
Legal::Something.find_for_B_in_placeb('xx', claim.eligible.first.bleble.indivcode) ||
Legal::Something.find_for_B_in_placeb('xx', claim.eligible.last.blublu.indivcode)
```

to improve efficiency and readability, stating it happens only when "indivcode" = "ASL"?
What else can I do?

Comment: The original seems fine, it encapsulates the complete business logic, it's linear and easy to follow, and it can be broken up into pieces later if you need the pieces. Splitting it up also seems fine. My question would be about where this lives, it probably should be in it's own object governing this business logic, not in a model or controller. The Code Review Stack Exchange might be a better choice.

Comment: Further to @Schwern's comment, I can only suggest one improvement: insert a space after `'day'` in `'day' => something...`, so that the three `=>`'s are vertically-aligned.  \\(ツ)/ Questions asking for improvements to working code should be posted at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than SO.

Comment: Note that `default_someting` would be more like `def something a || b || default_something; end` `a`, `b`, and `default_something` could cache the result of each query in the object if appropriate improving performance; `def a @a ||= Legal::Something.find_for_A_in_placea('xx', claim.blabla.identifier); end`. Finally, going the other way, it's possible all four queries could be combined into a single query: `Legal::Something.where(this: that).or(x: y).or(key: value)`. However, without some fancy SQL this will give up control of the order of the results.

Comment: @CarySwoveland when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". The OP has asked on CR and it might likely be closed as off-topic because it [is missing context](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652).